# change store by location

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I want to change store by location in magento. For that I create a popup of location dropdown when user open website in there browser, here user selects its location and website redirect to particular store.

```
public function getLocationInfoByIp($observer) {

        $location = $_POST['location'];
        switch ($location) {

            case "US": {
                  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('en');
                  break;
            }
            case "IN": {
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('de');
                break;
            }
            default: {
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('en');
                break;
            }
       }
 }
```

When I submit popup after selecting location from dropdown, It change store. But after refresh it again change store to default.

So please suggest to resolve this issue.

Comment: here extension.Please see http://www.atwix.com/magento/geoip-magento-store-switcher/

Comment: I have used that one too. it is also not worked

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you have the store code added to the URL's or not in the admin settings (`system->configuration->web->url options->add store code to urls`), or stores are under different domains, you can take 1 of 2 approaches.

With the store code setting enabled, or stores under different domains the store is determined purely by the URL, so to switch to a particular store you just need to redirect to the base URL (or some other page of your choosing) i.e.:

```
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeid);
$url = $store->getBaseUrl();
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
```

If you don't have the store code appearing in URL's and stores are under the same domain you just set a `store` cookie containing the code of the store you want to switch to:

```
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeid);
$url = $store->getBaseUrl();
Mage::app()->getCookie()->set(Mage_Core_Model_Store::COOKIE_NAME, $store->getCode(), true);
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
```